# After pushing my site on shared hosting blank page

Tags: laravel-8

I would like to completely reshuffle my site without interrupting its availability.
I use a shared hosting. On my domain, I created several subdomains one hosts the currently available site, the other is reserved for my reshuffling.
The root documents of the sites are respectively:

- subdomain1.domain.fr/public
- subdomain2.domain.fr/public

I am using the same .htaccess files on both subdomains.
The first one works. The second displays a blank page
On firefox there is no additional information.
On Brave or Google chrome an error 500 message is displayed.
Here is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And here are some useful values in .env

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

Thank you for help

Additional EDIT
when replacing the content of index.php with only phpinfo(); it display the page php info correctly.

Comment: have you pushed the two project in the same way? what are you doing to upload your project?

Comment: In fact I dont push. I use a transient repo on github. Push my local on github and then from the hosting pull the github repo. I did the same for the first site.

Comment: Added an Edit to the initial message

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, using

```
phpinfo(); exit;
```

in the index.php file and moving them statement after statement, I found that the vendor/autoload.php was missing.
And as who can do the most can do the least, I added the full vendor directory, Probably it is not necessary.